# what option controls numeric brace expansion in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I'm getting a really weird bug on one of my zsh installations. I can do this:

```
for k in {1..6}; do echo $k; done                                                                                    
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
```

but I can't step through it:

```
for k in {1..6..2}; do echo $k; done 
# {1..6..2}
```

I'm sure my current shell is zsh, and in a different computer it works, so I'm just wondering what option I might have set that changed the default behavior. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `{x..y}` syntax originated in `zsh` decades ago, `ksh93` was the one adding the `{x..y..step}` one and `zsh` only added it in version 4.3.10-test-3 in 2010.

You probably have an older version of `zsh` there.